# using curl to get data from opendatacommunities.org

Tags: api, curl

I want to use the API from opendatacommunities.org

the following code is used for the same. But I a get a "no acceptable resource available" message

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/api/v1/domestic/search?address=liverpool"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0")
$headers = array(); 
$headers[] = "Accept: text/json"; 
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); } 
curl_close ($ch);
```

Can any one help?

Comment: this site requests authorization so I was not able to test it, but I noticed some typo here.
•your URL looks malformed "search?ddress=liverpool" <- ?address <-missing "a"
•you forgot to put double quote after CURLOPT_URL
•in $headers authorization missing quote after your masked code XXX"<

you should refer to original documentation here : https://epc.opendatacommunities.org/docs/api/domestic

Comment: Hi, sorry for the typos. It appeared when i pasted the code here and edited the same. I have updated the same in the above thread

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was able to fix it as the code

```
$headers[] = "Accept: text/json";
```

was replaced with

```
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
```

thank you for the help DhamankarTejas